# Como executar um select dentro de uma condição IF/CASE?

Tags: sql, sql-server

gostaria de saber como posso usar um select como uma condição verdadeira ou falsa dentro de um case ou IF:

A query a retornar true ou false é esta:

```
SELECT * FROM Funcionario f WHERE (f.Email IS NULL OR RTRIM(f.Email)='') AND f.FuncionarioID=@funcionarioID
```

A condição é, se este select retornar uma linha Verdadeiro Senão Falso.

Algo parecido com isto:

```
IF (SELECT * FROM Funcionario f WHERE (f.Email IS NULL OR RTRIM(f.Email)='') AND f.FuncionarioID=1) THEN END
```

Answer (score 1):

Você tem que selecionar a expressão booleana que precisa. Os `*` é para pegar todas colunas. O `SELECT` serve para **selecionar* a informação que precisa, se é uma condição, use ela lá.

```
IF (SELECT (f.Email IS NULL OR RTRIM(f.Email) = '') FROM Funcionario f WHERE f.FuncionarioID = 1) THEN END
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Procedure/IfSelect.sql).

Comment: Eu preciso pegar o retorno de linhas desse select sabe, vi que no sql @@ROWCOUNT faz isso.

Comment: `@@ROWCOUNT` não tem nada com isso, pelo menos não com o que está na pergunta. Eu respondi o que foi perguntado, se seu problema é outro, precisa criar uma nova pergunta.